# NetFlow packet analyze

Tags: networking, sniffing, network-traffic, analysis

I configured Netflow on Cisco 7200 and Cisco send some info for my IP address.

[image]

According to the screenshot (*Wireshark*), `172.16.98.99` is Cisco's IP address and `172.16.98.28` is my IP address (*Destination*) for analyzing Netflow Packet.

Now, I can't understand the packets. **How to understand and implementation this protocol?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Netflow collector, which receives the Netflow records generated by the 7200, organizes them and displays the data in a meaningful format.  You can find commercial and freeware collectors with a simple Google search

Answer (score 0):

I'm Searched in google and gave many usefull link such as [NetFlow Version 9 Flow-Record Format](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/technologies/tk648/tk362/technologies_white_paper09186a00800a3db9.html), [NetFlow Export Datagram Format](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/netflow_collection_engine/3-6/user/guide/format.html), etc.
Now i can be analysis the **NetFlow** packets.

Comment: Grammar..... :|